# Need help with integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals

This is integral:

$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{x^3 (1-x)}}dx$

But I can write it like this:

So I can write $x$ as $\sqrt[4]{x^4}$

And I get:

$\int\sqrt[4]\frac{x}{1-x}dx$

Now I use substitution;
Not sure how to solve it now,only thing I can do is set t=$\sqrt[4]\frac{x}{1-x}dx$

so i get $\frac{x}{1-x}=t^4$

$x=\frac{t^4}{1+t^4}$

$dx=4(x-1)^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x} \right )^{3/4}dt$

$(\frac{x}{1-x})^{3/4}$ is $t^3$ so $dx=4(x-1)^2t^3 dt $

Now I bring this back to $\int\sqrt[4]\frac{x}{1-x}dx$
Now I have:

$\int t^4 4(x^2-2x+1)dt$;
so I use $x=\frac{t^4}{1+t^4}$ so change $x$;

now we have:

$4\int \left (\frac{t^4}{(1+t^4)^2}\right )dt$ so now I add +1-1;
and we get 2 integrals:

$4(\int \frac{dt}{1+t^4}$-$\int \frac{dt}{(1+t^4)^2})$

So here I stucks,how do I solve these 2

Sorry for my bad English,hopefully you will understand the problem.

Comment: Your post is actually unformatted. We can barely understand what your integral is.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition. It will be messy.

Comment: Is your integral:

$$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{x^3 (1-x)}} \, dx$$

or is it something else?

Comment: is your integral $$\int \frac{xdx}{\sqrt[4]{(x^3(1-x)})}$$

Comment: Yes,i re-edited

Comment: Seems already to have been considered:    
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191454/integrating-i-int-fracx-sqrt4x3a-xdx-a0?rq=1

Comment: Wolfram gives the answer as $$\sqrt[4]{-\frac{x}{x-1}} \left(\sqrt[4]{1-x} \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};\frac{5}{4};x\right)+x-1\right)$$ where $\,   _2F_1$ is a Hypergeometric function.